# select directory to save image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have the following code running

```
<a href="#" id="" download="">Save Image</a>
```

But I wanted to know if you have to choose the directory where the image will be saved in default it saves in 'downloads'

[if there is doubt about the question, here's something more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014870/canvas-url-to-download-image)

note: this link is to download a canvas

Comment: do you think a browser can save a file in a specific location in the user computer? If that would be possible anyone could potentially put auto installing viruses with you just visiting normal web pages. Thankfully that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the destination from the server side ( handled by the browser ), but you can use some work arounds like [this](http://www.ardentedge.com/pr_fd.htm)

alltrough i would not recommend it, since it's a voiolation of user space.
Also it's browser dependent, where it will be saved, you can set up firefox for example, to open by default, save without question, of remember the last save path, but that is all choosen by the user, on hes side.

Comment: what helps me is this, specify a directory and save the image it (ex: c:\images)