# Js download canvas through Tampermonkey not working (corrupted file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, tampermonkey

I have a gallery of images displayed through a html 5 canvas and some buttons to go back and forth.
I did a javascript script that basically gets the canvas and downloads the image and I put it in a Tampermonkey user script to automate the thing for the whole gallery and download all the images.

The problem is that if I run the script manually in the Chrome Developer tools console, it works flawlessly.

If I run it through Tampermonkey, the majority of the images downloaded are corrupted, while some are good and display correctly. So not every image is corrupted.

It looks like it has some problems with the data stream or something and it gets it incomplete, like the page isn't fully loaded or the script has not enough time to download the image.

I've also tried to put some abundant sleeps to give more time to the page, but it doesn't change nothing.

These are the 2 scripts I made, which do the same thing, but download the file in a different way:

Script 1:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           somesite
// @description    download image
// @namespace      somesite
// @version        1.0
// @match          https://somesite.com/somegallery/*
// @license        tttt
// @copyright      tttt
// @grant          none
// @run-at         document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

//Gets the canvas and converts it
    var image = document.getElementById("the-canvas").toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    window.location.href=image;

    //Check page number, if last page, no click to next page is made
    if(eval('parseInt(' + $("#main > h1").text().substr($("#main > h1").text().lastIndexOf(" Page ")+5).replace(" of ", ") !== parseInt(") + ');'))
    {
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary float-right")[1].click();},Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1500);
    }
```

This downloads through redirection, so you get files with name "download, download(1), download(2)...."  without the possibility to choose a filename

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           somesite
// @description    download image
// @namespace      somesite
// @version        1.0
// @match          https://somesite.com/somegallery/*
// @license        tttt
// @copyright      tttt
// @grant          none
// @run-at         document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

$().ready(function(){
    var image = document.getElementById("the-canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = 'Page ' + $("#main > h1").text().substr($("#main > h1").text().lastIndexOf(" Page ")+5) + '.jpg';
        link.href = image;

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    //Check page number, if last page, no click is made
    if(eval('parseInt(' + $("#main > h1").text().substr($("#main > h1").text().lastIndexOf(" Page ")+5).replace(" of ", ") !== parseInt(") + ');'))
    {
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary float-right")[1].click();},Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000);
    }
});
```

This gets the page number so I can get some files with a decent name "Page 1 of 100.jpg... etc".

Any idea why the images are corrupted if I run through Tampermonkey and are ok and fine if I run them manually through chrome dev tools?

EDIT:
Looks like page it's not fully loaded. This improves the solution, but it's still time dependant and so, if the page takes more time than what I set as setTimeout, it will still fail. So it's still heavily dependant on user interaction and manual human check

Isn't there a reliable method to detect if a page has loaded?
document ready, jquery.ready and tampermonkey page-idle are unreliable it seems

Current solution:

```
   // ==UserScript==
    // @name           somesite
    // @description    download image
    // @namespace      somesite
    // @version        1.0
    // @match          https://somesite.com/somegallery/*
// @license        tttt
// @copyright      tttt
// @grant          none
// @run-at         document-end
// ==/UserScript==

$().ready(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
$("#the-canvas").click(function(){
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = 'Page ' + $("#main > h1").text().substr($("#main > h1").text().lastIndexOf(" Page ")+5) + '.png';
        link.href = image;

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    //Check page number, if last page, no click is made
    if(eval('parseInt(' + $("#main > h1").text().substr($("#main > h1").text().lastIndexOf(" Page ")+5).replace(" of ", ") !== parseInt(") + ');'))
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary float-right")[1].click();
    }});

    setTimeout(function(){$("#the-canvas").click()},13000)
});
```

Still, it doesn't solve and some images get corrupted anyway.....

this is frustrating and depressing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If I recall correctly, you need to get the Content of the Canvas first. Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014870/canvas-url-to-download-image

Comment: @Twisty not really they're not doing anything that solves my problem.